# Is waiting inside a callback safe in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a BeginRead that calls a ReadCallback function upon completion. What I want to do in the callback is wait for a ManualResetEvent on a buffer to tell me if the buffer is empty or not, so I can issue a new BeginRead if I need more data. I have implemented this and it works. But my question is : is it safe to wait inside a callback?
I'm new to C#, if these were regular threads I wouldn't have doubts, but I'm not sure how C# treats callbacks.

Thank you.

Comment: If callback is *asynchronous*, then you are free to do anything, as it's called more like this: `Task.Run(callback)`. Otherwise (if caller uses callback result) you are blocking, but blocking may be safe (if you call function using callback from within thread). In case of [`Stream.BeginRead`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.beginread.aspx) it should be safe to wait.

Comment: There isn't enough information to answer. What is the `BeginRead` method? `Socket.BeginRead`, `FileStream.BeginRead`? or what? Who signals the `ManualResetEvent`? How long it would take? etc

Comment: @Sinatr No it is not safe to wait in a threadpool thread (for a large amount of time). If there are several waits pending, then you're forcing the threadpool to create threads unnecessarily.

Comment: Yes, the call is asynchronous, I was referring to NetworkStream.BeginRead. The ManualResetEvent is signaled from a Read function of my own design when the buffer that I'm using gets empty. My working model is something similar to producer/consumer. I get data from the stream with BeginRead, put that data in a buffer and when my Read function is called, move the data from one buffer to another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

APM callbacks are called on the thread-pool in all cases that I can think of.

That reduces your question to "Can I block thread-pool threads?". The answer to that is generally yes but it has downsides.

It is "safe" to do so until you exhaust the pool (then you risk deadlocks and extreme throughput reduction like >1000x).

The other downsides are the usual downsides of blocking threads in general. They cost a lot of memory to keep around. Lots of threads can cause lots of context switches.

Can't you just use await? I imagine your code to look like this:

```
while (true) {
 var readResult = await ReadAsync(...);
 await WaitForSomeConditionAsync(); //Instead of ManualResetEvent.
}
```

No blocking. Very simple code. There is no need to do anything special to issue the next read. It just happens as part of the loop.

> My working model is something similar to producer/consumer.

Sounds like a good use for TPL Dataflow. Dataflow automates the forwarding of data, the waiting and throttling. It supports async to the fullest.